# Should we abandon shell script (bash) and use Python as much as possible

Tags: linux, bash, shell, python

The more I write Python, the more I hate the shell (bash) script

e.g.

```
if ["foo" = "foo"]; then
   echo "expression evaluated as true"
fi
```

Guess what is error? I need a **space** after `[`, that is so hard to debug and non-sense, in Python, which is short and easy

```
if "foo" == "foo":
    print "expression evaluated as true"
```

As Python is avaliable in most system now, do you think it is a good chance to abandon shell script for new function and move to Python?

For those you are still writing new shell script, what are the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still write very elaborate scripts in bash. The reason? Mostly because I'm used to it and bash is present on all systems (just make sure you don't do #!/bin/sh because you might have dash on some systems...).

Another reason is very tight integration with system commands.

A good reason I want to start getting used to perl or python, is because bash has no exceptions. It keeps running the script if there is an error you forgot to catch. And even doing "command || exit" won't work, because it doesn't work in pipes.

Comment: You can use `set -e` and it will exit on every error.

Comment: Except that it will also stop your script if you grep and get no match (which can be a perfectly normal situation).

Comment: If you put that `grep` into an `if`, it will not stop the script. But yes, it is not as fine grained as exceptions. I do like Python more than Bash.

Comment: If you put `grep` somewhere in a pipe in an if, it does stop the script, though.

Comment: This is the point why Bash is hard to really understand. I do not know the exact rules of the exist status, and I am just glad that Python exists.

Comment: 'Another reason is very tight integration with system commands.' Yes, we have seen that.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. 1) `subprocess` is annoying to chain. 2) It's easier to type `for f in * ; do foo "$f" ; done` as a one-off than to write a Python script to do the same.

Comment: pbs (https://github.com/amoffat/pbs) is a good alternative (need to install separately)

Comment: your link is a 404 and duckduckgo told me "PBS will no longer be supported.  Please upgrade here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh "

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use both shell scripting and Perl scripting. When I need to deal with system commands mostly, I find it easier to write a shell script.

In other cases when I need to use some library which I could not find its equivalent in shell or does not know a command that can do it easily, I switch to Perl. This is the case when I need to connect to a database. I use Perl DBI module. I am talking about Perl, but the same idea applies when talking about Python.

It is a good idea to master both. Sometimes, you need this and in other cases you need the other.